# protobuf-net unable to import

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

I'm trying protobuf-net contract-first but for some reason I'm getting the following errors when I try to import `user_session_2.proto` because it depends on `shared_1.proto`. They are both in different directories. How do I deal with that issue?

[image]

[image]

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="protobuf-net" Version="3.1.25" />
    <PackageReference Include="protobuf-net.BuildTools" Version="3.1.25">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <AdditionalFiles Include="Protos\common\shared_1.proto" />
    <AdditionalFiles Include="Protos\WebAPI\user_session_2.proto" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
</Project>
```

### Protos/common/shared_1.proto

```
syntax = "proto2";

package shared_1;

...
```

### Protos/WebAPI/user_session_2.proto

```
syntax = "proto2";

package user_session_2;

import "common/shared_1.proto";

...
```

Comment: Never found a solution to this?

Comment: @Deantwo nope I didn't